# TailwindCSS rem and px

Tags: tailwind-css

In the [TailwindCSS docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width) `1rem` is commented as being equivalent to `16px`, even though (as far as I know) this is just the browser default and may be changed by the user.

Are the comments in the docs just an indication of what those `rem` are likely to be in `px`, or does TailwindCSS actually have some logic that makes our given `1rem` equivalent to the rendered `16px` no matter what the user does?

Comment: Are you familiar with `text-size-adjust:` ?

Comment: @Dai I do, after having [MDNed it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust). Are you saying that tailwind uses that property somewhere or are you suggesting to use that property to test whether tailwind's rem size changes?

Comment: Tailwind's `preflight.css` [specifies](https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.2.1/src/css/preflight.css) `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;` - so at this point I'm unsure (and I'm not a fan of "reset.css"-type techniques...)

Comment: @Dai thanks for that preflight.css I should have checked it by myself. You can turn the comment into an answer if you want. By the way I pretend I didn't see the comment you made and removed 10 seconds later lol

Comment: It's not guaranteed that browsers will respect `-webkit-text-size-adjust` or `text-size-adjust` though, just warning you.

Comment: @Dai yeah MDN says to be careful with this experimental technology. So anyway tailwind intention is to map 1rem to 16px, which at the moment is not guaranteed to happen, just very likely. Thanks again. If you write an answer you got my upvote.

Comment: ...I don't know if I really want to be seen giving advice for Tailwind

Comment: @Dai it's the way css is used nowdays lol

Comment: Yeah, and that makes me depressed.

Comment: "Everything is terrible" man you probably would benefit from some physical exercise and healthy eating. Mind and body are more connected than you may have thought